# Powershell: Can I manipulate scope of Push-Location dir stack somehow?

Tags: powershell

What I have is a module of functions each doing its stuff.

What I want is that every function pushed the directory it was called from to a stack so that I can go back and call it again easily if it fails as well as trace back directories I used my custom commands in.

Adding `pushd` to function body doesn't help since function's  stack is within its scope. I tried assigning `Get-Location -Stack` result to a global variable and piping it to `Set-Location` within a module but it didn't seem to help.

Is there any way I can force-change scope of `pushd` within a function to global? Or any other way I can make a trace-back? I can write my own global stack as an array of paths and manage it with custom functions I guess, but could I be missing something here?

*UPDATE:* if function is defined globally `pushd` from its body indeed modifies global stack, but it doesn't work if function is sourced from a module for some reason.

Comment: AFAIK, location stacks are global and not scoped to functions. Do you have any evidence that it is other way around?

Comment: @PetSerAl Well, it gets strange actually: if I create a script in Powershell ISE with `pushd` in its body and run it (function defined in global scope, I guess), `popd` works fine outside, but when I run a function from an imported module - it doesn't. Binding stack to definition scope makes no sense for modules, but looks that way to me right now.

Comment: You are right, @ephemeris. After some testing I see, that location stacks are scoped to `SessionState`, which is separate per module, but two functions from same module should use same location stacks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the `-StackName` parameter of `Push-Location` creates a global stack or not, but I assume it probably doesn't.  Might be worth testing.

It might be easiest to create your own stack object, and either create a parameter for all your functions to pass it, or else create the stack as a global or script scoped variable.

```
$PathStack = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]';
$PathStack.Push((Get-Location));
$PathStack.Push((Push-Location -Path $NewPath -PassThru));
Set-Location -Path ($PathStack.Pop());
Set-Location -Path ($PathStack.Pop());
```

As a global:

```
$Global:PathStack = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]';
```

As a script scope:

```
$Script:PathStack = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was running into this issue trying to use the ConfigurationManager cmdlets from within a custom built module.  To make the cmdlets accessible from function in the module I had to import the module using the global scope modifier:

```
[string] $CcmModulePath = (Join-Path -Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} -ChildPath 'Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1')
Import-Module $CcmModulePath -Scope Global -ErrorAction Stop
```